# Convergence or divergence of $\int_0^2 \frac{\sin^2x}{x^p}\,dx$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration

I am starting to learn a little about analysis and convergence of Riemann integrals. I came across this problem and it stomped me. I want to find the values of $p$ for which the integral converges.

$$\int_0^2 \frac{\sin^2x}{x^p}\,dx$$

My approach was noting that: $\sin^2x \le \vert \sin x\vert$ and that $\vert \frac{\sin x}{x^p}\vert \le \frac1{x^p} $ then $\vert \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^p}\vert \le \frac1{x^p} $

Integration by parts yields:

$$\int_0^2 \frac{\sin^2x}{x^p}\,dx= \left[ \frac{x^{-p}}{2} \left(x-0.5\sin{2x} \right) \right]_0^2+\frac p2 \int_0^2 x^{-p}-\frac {x^{-p-1}}{2}\sin {2x}\,dx $$

$$= \frac1{2^p}\left( 1 - \frac {\sin4}{2}\right)+\frac p2\left[ \frac{2^{-p+1}}{-p+1} \right]_0^2- \frac p4\int_0^2 x^{-p-1}\sin {2x}\,dx$$

$$= \frac1{2^p}\left( 1 - \frac {\sin4}{2}\right) +\frac {p}{2^p\left(-p+1\right)}-\frac p4\int_0^2 x^{-p-1}\sin {2x}\,dx$$
$$$$
But since $\vert x^{-p-1}\sin{2x} \vert \le x^{-p-1}$ and $p+1 \gt 1$, then $\frac p4\int_0^2 x^{-p-1}\sin {2x}\,dx$ is convergent because $\int_0^2 x^{-p}\,dx$ convergent for $p \gt1$

So I arrived at the conclusion that for $p \gt1$, $\int_0^2 \frac{\sin^2x}{x^p}\,dx$ converges, since all of the terms to the right are finite and the integral on the right also convergent. On the other hand I checked with Wolfram Alpha and  it says $\int_0^2 \frac{\sin^2x}{x^3}\,dx$ does not converge, yet $p=3 \gt 1$. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{x^p} dx$ is not convergent for $p>1$. For example $\int_{0}^2 \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \lim_{m\to 0^{+}} \frac{-1}{x}|_m^2  = \infty$. You are maybe thinking about $\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}$, which is convergent for all $a>0$ and $p>1$

Comment: Right, I completely forgot that the lower bound needed to be greater that $0$. Then to continue with my proof I would need to continue on integrating? or separate my last integral into two with bounds $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^2$respectively? And then perhaps do a limit on the integral with lower bound $0$ such as $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_t^1$?

Comment: A quick computer calculation (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ited2jtxnq) shows the integral only converges for $p<3$. I would maybe start by thinking along the lines of: if the integral converges then $\lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^p} = 0$ and L-Hospital gaurantees $p<2$; I'm still stuck on the case where $p \in[2,3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align}
|\sin x | \le |x|
\end{align}
when $|x|$ is small. In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
\int^2_0 \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^p}\ dx \le \int^2_0 \frac{dx}{x^{p-2}}<\infty
\end{align}
provided $p-2<1$ or $p<3$.

Suppose $p\ge 3$. I need to show that the integral is divergent to complete the problem. In fact, it suffices to show that the following integral is divergent
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{p}}\ dx
\end{align}
since $\pi/2<2$ and the integrand is non-negative.

Let us make the observation that
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\pi}x \le \sin x
\end{align}
on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$ (draw a picture to convince yourself). This means that
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^p}\ dx \ge \frac{4}{\pi^2}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{x^{p-2}} = \infty
\end{align}
provided $p\ge 3$.

Comment: I cannot see how you went from $ \vert \sin x \vert \le \vert x \vert$ to the integrals and the conclusion that $p-2 \lt 1$

Comment: Could you explain to me what is stumping you?

Comment: how can you see that $\int_0^2 \frac {\sin^2x}{x^p} \le \int_0^2 \frac 1{x^{p-2}}$

Comment: Let me ask you this: where did I use the fact that $ \sin x \le x$?

Comment: We want $x$ small, then taking $x^{t}$ if $t \lt 1$ will satisfy $x$ small right? so I think I see where the $ \lt 1$ comes from, but what about the $p-2$?

Comment: I think my comment is a little bit more straightforward than that.

Comment: So $\vert \sin x \vert \le \vert x \vert$ then $\vert \sin^2 x \vert \le \vert x^2 \vert $ then since $\vert \frac {\sin x}{x^p} \vert \le \frac{1}{x^p}$ we have $\vert \frac {\sin^2 x}{x^p} \vert \le \frac{1}{x^p} \cdot \frac 1{x^2}$? Is that it?

Comment: close, but your algebra is wrong.

Comment: Is it that $\left( \vert x \vert \right)^2 \neq \left( \vert x^2 \vert \right) $?

Comment: No. $|x|^2 = |x^2|$.

Comment: I think I missed a square on $\vert \frac {\sin^2 x}{x^{2+p}} \vert$ thus making $ p \to 2+p$

Comment: Ah never mind, I think I got it, the $x^2$ should be on top since we are squaring $\sin x$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So it goes as follows: $| \sin x | \le | x |$ then $\vert \sin^2 x \vert \le \vert x^2 \vert$ and since $\vert \frac{\sin x}{x^p} \vert \le \vert \frac {1}{x^p}$ then  $\vert \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^p} \vert \le \vert \frac {x^2}{x^p}$

Comment: Note that you didn't really use $|\frac{\sin x}{x^p}| \le \frac{1}{x^p}$ since you replace $\sin x$ by $x$ not $1$.

Comment: And then the $p-2 \lt 1$ comes from the fact that if $p-2 \lt 1$ then $x$ is small?

Comment: When $p-2<1$, try integrating $\int^2_0 \frac{dx}{x^{p-2}}$ directly.

Comment: We have: $\frac{2^{-p+3}}{-p+3}$. But I don't see what you mean?

Comment: If $p = 4$ does your answer make sense?

Comment: taking it back to the integral, $\int_0^2 \frac 1{x^2}$ diverges. But plugging it in the antiderivative yield $-0.5$, why does that not make sense?

Comment: Anyway, I think you understand most of the points. I will let you think about it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the lower bound.

By Taylor, we have
$$\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^p}=\frac 1{x^p}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac {2^{2n-1}} {(2n)!} x^{2n}$$
$$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^p}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac {2^{2n-1}} {(2n)!}\int x^{2n-p}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^p}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{ 2^{2 n-1} }{(2 n)! \,(2 n-p+1)}x^{2 n-p+1}$$ The very firs term being $x^{3-p}$, the requirement for convergence is then $p<3$.

*Just for your curiosity, the definite integral is given by*
$$\frac{2^{-p} (\cos (4)-1)}{p-1}-\frac{2^{4-p} }
   {(p-3) (p-1)}\,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{3-p}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{5-p}{2};-4\right)$$

Comment: How can you determine the interval of convergence (i.e. that the series converges) just by looking at the first term and showing that the exponent must be greater that $0$?